# Stopping form prepopulation in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In an MVC view with a form on it and given the following code using HTML helpers:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { id = "firstName", maxlength = "50", @class = "form-input" })
```

Is there a way to stop this form automatically populating the fields with data? I know it's by design and in most cases is helpful but in this case I want to be able to turn that functionality off.

To clarify - If I have a ViewModel with this property in it:

```
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

I understand that the HTMLHelper TextBoxFor will allow me to use the strongly typed

```
m => m.FirstName
```

when creating the input.

That's fine. However, if I have the ViewModel populated with data then it also shows this data in the input field, this is by design and I get that.

Now, imagine you wanted the strength of the strongly typed aspect but without the automatic filling of the data.

The only option appears to be:

```
@Html.TextBox("myTextBox", "value goes here", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Which is brittle where the name / id values are concerned. I prefer the strongly typed nature of the TextBoxFor but can't have that without also automatically showing whatever the ViewModel data is.

Comment: what do you mean by "automatically populating the fields with data" ? can you please specify fields? In case you don't auto population, you can always use <input> tag. If you are concerned about "0" for int data types, it is default behavior and you have to write custom html helpers to overcome it

Comment: Just use a model with default values. The form doesn't "prepopulate" anything, it does what you asked - creates a textbox and binds it to the `FirstName` property. If you want that textbox to be empty, make sure that `FirstName` is empty

Comment: But is not the case that if my ViewModel is populated with data then it will fill that FirstName input with that data?  The strongly typed aspect of the TextBoxFor I understand but not why it's filling the data automatically.

Comment: If you want the textbox to be blank and the model not to be blank then you do not want to use the helper.... you should use a pure html input element. I would reconsider your design as this is not really the way you are supposed to use MVC

Comment: I agree, and in this case it's a backward use case, I'm trying to retro fit functionality to an existing system. I was hoping there would be a flag like 'ShowData' when using the helper that would allow you to show or hide the bound data.

Comment: Sounds to me like it's the browser that is pre-populating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about the browser behaviour here, so you want to turn off `autocomplete`. You can use this on a per input basis:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { ..., autocomplete = "off" })
```

Or you can do it on the whole form:

```
@Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete="off" })
```

***EDIT:***
Reading your comments it seems you're populating the view model with the values and seeing them when you render the view. In which case, the answer is simple, reset the model before passing it to the view:

```
return ViewModel(new TModel());
```

Comment: I've essentially followed this suggestion, although have not created a new empty ViewModel I've instead just stopped certain elements from being populated.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton I thought that might be the case. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

While passing the viewmodel to view in controller you can set those properties to blank value or null for which you want empty textboxes in UI.

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing